# Winxp share on Samba 4.2.14-Debian (10.0.0.6) not allowing guest write acces

Tags: samba, fstab

Winxp guest cannot create files or folders on shared samba drive.

How can I fix it?  I get "access denied" and sudo chown does not change permissions.

Here is fat32 SD card fstab:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1    /media/card     auto     auto,rw,async,user,nofail  0  0
```

Here is testparm sections:

```
[global]
        server role = standalone server
        security = USER
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        preferred master = Yes
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[share]
        comment = Samba share
        path = /media
        read only = No
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
        guest ok = Yes
```

c-:

Comment: mount `/dev/mmcblk0p1` with option `mode=0777`.